# How to unzip a blob (xlsx file) with google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the contents of a xlsx file with Google Script.

Step 1 is to get a blob and unzip it.

Here is my code :

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById(docId);
var b1 = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
var b2 = Utilities.unzip(b1)[0];
```

But I keep getting an "Invalid Argument" error on the last line.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the content type to application/zip - the unzip method won't accept anything else.